# angularjs visual feedback for server requests

Tags: http, angularjs

How is the angular way to show visual feedback to the user that the appp is waiting for an answer from the server?

Currently i have factory with following code

```
app.factory('MyAppFact', ['$http', '$q', 
function($http, $q) {
    function _success(data, status) {
        document.body.classList.remove('waitserver')
        if (data.status == 'OK') {
            this.resolve(data);
        } else {
            this.reject(data);
        }   
    }
    function _error(data, status) {
        document.body.classList.remove('waitserver')
        this.reject(status})    
    }
    return {
        changeLocale: function(locale){
            var d = $q.defer();
            document.body.classList.add('waitserver');
            $http.get('/changeLocale/'+locale).success(_success.bind(d), 
                _error.bind(d));
            return d.promise;
        },
        login: function(uname, passwd, keep) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            document.body.classList.add('waitserver');
            $http.post('/login', {uname:uname, passwd:passwd, keep:keep}
                ).success(_success.bind(d), _error.bind(d));
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        register: function(user) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            document.body.classList.add('waitserver');
            $http.post('/register', {user:user}).success(_success.bind(d), 
                _error.bind(d));
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        ...

    }
}]);
```

Although this code works, I am adding a css class in to the document body, while according to the angularjs docs, I am not supposed to change the DOM in a factory method, thereby violating the clear separation of the MVC

But I don't see how I can accomplish the separation in this case.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743656/angular-ui-grid-how-to-show-a-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can combine some global state, a `ng-class` directive (applied to the `<body>` or the wrapper element of your dynamic, Angular-managed content) and the HTTP interceptors described [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

So the global state would be something like an active requests counter, implemented as a service or a member of the `$rootScope`. Lets consider the 2nd for simplicity, although the 1st seems more correct:

```
$rootScope.activeRequestsCounter = 0;
```

You register the interceptors that manipulate the counter:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($rootScope) {
    function increase() {
        $rootScope.activeRequestsCounter++;
    }

    function decrease() {
        $rootScope.activeRequestsCounter--;
    }

    return {
        request: increase,
        requestError: decrease,
        response: decrease,
        responseError: decrease
    };
});


// in some config block:
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

In the HTML:

```
<body ng-class="{waitserver: activeRequestsCounter &gt; 0}">
```

This is the principle of operation, details may need refinement. What you gain is that you no longer need to worry about adding/removing the class in each service call. You can invoke multiple services and the counter will update correctly. And you do not manipulate DOM inside the services (cleaner code).

Comment: Thanks. I will do it slightly different, but setting a $rootScope variable does the trick