# Display Loading Icon or Loading Progress Bar using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to display the loading Icon or loading Progress bar using angularjs. I mean something like this which used in jquery `$("body").addClass("loading");`, `$("body").removeClass("loading");`, I saw some links for progress bar which is of like youtube loading bar but i don't want like that I want simple progress bar or loading iage or loading icon or loading bar which show bar moving from module to module, tabs to tabs. Is there any link or function which explain clearly how to use it.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular#answer-15033322

Comment: I need a simple something like this https://github.com/voronianski/ngprogress-lite#ngprogress-lite but the problem with this it is showing like youtube way

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue, but you could try to look at a similar loading progress bar like this one: **https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar** (since Angular Loading bar uses interceptors you might also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743656/angular-ui-grid-how-to-show-a-loader/18785265#18785265 )

Answer (score 6):

if you dont want to implement it yourself, below are few links.

[angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) or [angular-sham-spinner](https://github.com/harinair/angular-sham-spinner)

also read this [BLOG](http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/) which details how the spinner works with angularjs

**EDIT** as per comments

```
app.directive("spinner", function(){
return: {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {enable:"="},
template: <div class="spinner" ng-show="enable"><img src="content/spinner.gif"></div>
}
});
```

i havent tested the code but directive wont be more complex than this...

Comment: both links are good but they are using $http, i don't want to use $http

Comment: i think then you will have to write a custom directive... which receives a boolean to show or hide the spinner... thats all it would take...too simple

Answer (score 4):

View

```
<div ng-show="loader.loading">Loading</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.loader.loading = true;  // false
```

Add this also on top of your controller

```
  $scope.loader = { 

              loading : false ,

             };
```

[Show and hide loading bar](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/04/show-and-hide-in-angular-js.html)

Comment: Can't read property loading undefined error is coming like this

Comment: set this $scope.loader= {  loading : false; };  in your controller